# Vectorize an iterrows function that removes duplicate values, keeping only the first

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a script that uses iterrows and have read that this is an inefficient method and would like to refine my code. But after reading other questions on the topic I haven't found the answer to my specific example. I'm a complete amateur coder so would appreciate any assistance in getting better.

I just want to remove duplicates in a series, keeping only the first and leaving blanks for subsequent rows with the same time. I keep the first row's time no matter what, so I start with comparing the second value.

```
def clean_times(df):

    time = df.iloc[1]['Result']  # initilize to the first time gap
    if ':' in time:
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            if index > 1:
                if row['Result'] == time:
                    df.loc[index, 'Result'] = ''
                else:
                    time = row['Result']
    return df
    time = ''
```

```
x = [{'Result':'4:51:36'},{'Result':'0:01:27'},{'Result':'0:02:19'},{'Result':'0:02:42'},{'Result':'0:02:57'},{'Result':'0:02:57'},{'Result':'0:02:57'},{'Result':'0:02:57'},{'Result':'0:02:57'},{'Result':'0:02:57'},{'Result':'0:02:57'},{'Result':'0:02:57'},{'Result':'0:02:57'},{'Result':'0:02:57'},{'Result':'0:02:57'},{'Result':'0:02:57'},{'Result':'0:02:57'},{'Result':'0:02:57'},{'Result':'0:03:03'},{'Result':'0:03:03'},{'Result':'0:03:23'},{'Result':'0:03:23'},{'Result':'0:03:23'},{'Result':'0:03:57'},{'Result':'0:03:57'},{'Result':'0:03:57'},{'Result':'0:03:57'},{'Result':'0:03:57'},{'Result':'0:03:57'},{'Result':'0:03:57'},{'Result':'0:03:57'},{'Result':'0:03:57'},{'Result':'0:03:57'},{'Result':'0:04:02'},{'Result':'0:04:15'},{'Result':'0:04:15'},{'Result':'0:04:25'},{'Result':'0:04:25'},{'Result':'0:04:25'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df1 = clean_times(df)
```

Result

```
Result
0   4:51:36
1   0:01:27
2   0:02:19
3   0:02:42
4   0:02:57
5   
6   
7   
8   
9   
10  
11  
12  
13  
14  
15  
16  
17  
18  0:03:03
19  
20  0:03:23
21  
22  
23  0:03:57
24  
25  
26  
27  
28  
29  
30  
31  
32  
33  0:04:02
34  0:04:15
35  
36  0:04:25
37  
38
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `mask` with a condition on the next (shifted) row:

```
df['Result'] = df['Result'].mask(df['Result']==df['Result'].shift(), '')
```

output:

```
     Result
0   4:51:36
1   0:01:27
2   0:02:19
3   0:02:42
4   0:02:57
5          
6          
7          
8          
9          
10         
11         
12         
13         
14         
15         
16         
17         
18  0:03:03
19         
20  0:03:23
21         
22         
23  0:03:57
24         
25         
26         
27         
28         
29         
30         
31         
32         
33  0:04:02
34  0:04:15
35         
36  0:04:25
37         
38
```